# TECLADO DIMINUI AO SETAR android:inputType="number""

Tags: java, android-activity

Colocando tal configuração em um EditText, ao compilar o teclado fica "largado" na tela

segue o xml da EditText

```xml
   <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtIP"
            android:layout_width="652dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

ficando da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este é o comportamento mesmo. Ao configurar o input type para number o android automaticamente abre o teclado numérico, ou altera do teclado completo para o numérico, se você não quiser esse comportamento o mais fácil é alterar o input type para text.

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: Eu gostaria que ele ficasse numerico porém com o comportamento do teclado normal!

Comment: @iDecks esse comportamento você não controla. Isso varia de aparelhos. Se houver alguma forma de controlar isso, seria usando o contexto, mas eu acredito que não há. O que você pode fazer é montar o seu próprio teclado...

Comment: Vou deixar o teclado original e atribuir uma mascara para deixar o usuario digitar somente numeros, obrigado!

Comment: @iDecks é uma opção interessante.